# How fast can my spouse get her green card based on my green card?

Tags: usa, greencard, chinese-citizens

I'm not a US citizen, I received my GC in June 2018. My girlfriend is Chinese citizen and studies in US. Her legal standard expires in 2 years.

How long is the process of adding my spouse to my green card - If we get married?
What are the steps of the process, after we get married?

On the web site [travel.state.gov here](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/legal/visa-law0/visa-bulletin/2019/visa-bulletin-for-july-2019.html) Visa Bulletin shows "C" or "current" under the application category F2A. Does it mean that if the marriage happens now we can file all documents immediately and can get GC really fast?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This month bulletin is indeed unusual as the F2A Final Action dates are current. So, yes, you may apply concurrently for a Family Petition (I-130) and the Adjustment of Status (I-485).

However, that does not means that the GC will be approved fast. The processing time depends on your field office and can vary from 4 months to over 2 years.

In summary the steps are:

1. File all appropriate forms with supporting evidence (I-130, I-485, I-765, etc)
2. Attend Biometrics Appointment (Beneficiary)
3. Attend Interview so the Immigration Officer can verify that you have a real marriage.

These are very high-level steps of a complicated process. There's lots of documentation online to assist you with more specifics. You can also ask here other questions.